# org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.PortInUseException: Port 80 is already in use

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This happens when application is launched via run as spring boot through STS.

**Spring boot:** 
**1.4.0.M1**

I have an IIS running on port 80 but however I have changed the sever.port through STS configuration properties to **8090**. 
[STS Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqgvG.png)

Why STS embedded tomcat is using the port 80 even after it is changed? Kind of puzzled.

> 2016-04-15 05:22:03,985 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication -
>   Application startup failed
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.PortInUseException: **Port
>   80 is already in use**    at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.checkThatConnectorsHaveStarted(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:187)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:170)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:768)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:362)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1172)
>     at
>   com.jbhunt.web.FinanceClaimsApplication.main(FinanceClaimsApplication.java:71)

I do not find an option to change the port other than the above
mentioned. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you maybe have a conflicting setting in the `.properties` or `.yaml` file? E.g. `management.port` using actuator?

Comment: I have no property defined in `.properties` or in `.yaml` file. I tried mentioning the `management.port` to 8091 in STS property dialog but still no luck.

Comment: Did you passed any arguments in the second tab?

Comment: Boot's default port for HTTP is 8080, so you must have something setting it to 80

Comment: Nope, nowhere it is set to 80. I even set it to 8090. Have not passed anything in second tab.

Comment: I tried -Dserver.port=8090 but no luck then removed it

Comment: Open arguments tab in STS and type the following `--server.port=8090`. It will override default Boot port. You don't need to use local tomcat to run spring boot application use `spring-boot-maven-plugin` (dev tools) to make application executable. STS has special boot tab to run boot projects.

Comment: `-Dserver.port=9000` in the VM Arguments works for me. See this [screenshot](http://imgur.com/BpKhzxH)

Comment: I did try `-Dserver.port=9000` in the VM arguments but the same Sanjay. @Anton: STS not using embedded tomcat rather than local tomcat?

Comment: Anyone from spring community to address this issue?

Comment: Got  it working when it comes form `application.properties` but not sure why it is not working when set it as vm arguments -`Dserver.port=8090`. Spring community should be able to throw some light on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your test class that load a context with a random port ([working-with-random-ports](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-working-with-random-ports)).

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

WebEnvironment can bo set with the constants: RANDOM_PORT, DEFINED_PORT, MOCK or NONE.

> The webEnvironment attribute allows specific “web environments” to be configured for the test. You can start tests with a MOCK servlet environment or with a real HTTP server running on either a RANDOM_PORT or a DEFINED_PORT.